# What happens to seismic waves reflected back to the surface?

Tags: geology, geophysics, waves, seismic

What would be the behavior of seismic waves when it hit the geological media?

The waves coming from a source hits different boundaries with different energies, the wave will be reduced in energy by then (let us say at boundary number 100), the wave will reflect back due to changes in rock physical properties and so on, the reflected wave will pass through boundary 99, I am pretty sure it will not just pass and it will face different boundary (99) with low energy, and so on with boundaries 98, 88, 87..etc. The issue is how we're going to detect boundary 100, what will be the equation for it?

I have been revising the well known Zoeppritz and Shuey equations, and they didn't give more details on this.

Comment: Soliciting off-site contact is not appreciated here. You should expect answers and requests for clarification here, publicly, not via your phone or etc.

Comment: There is no magic about the $n$th reflection. It behaves the same as the $(n-1)$st reflection.